# How can I make a dry dilution refrigerator quiet?

Tags: experimental-technology, cryogenics

The pulse tubes are really loud.
We've wrapped the helium lines in sound absorbing foam, and we have a cage around the top of the cryostat also lined with foam, but it's still pretty loud.

To make this an interesting physics question I ask: how is the sound getting from the mechanism to my ears?
Does the sound travel through the support frame?
Through the helium lines?

Given the transduction channel, is there an effective way to reduce the noise?

Comment: I am curious if any of the close voters know anything about experimental cryogenic systems? The usual set of meta posts apply: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5553/ http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2948/ and http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4146/520.

Comment: @dmckee I will be the first to confess that I don't know ANYTHING about  experimental cryogenic systems :S Maybe I was too hasty to recommend closing the Q

Comment: To be sure the question makes no particular reference to an experimental context, which may have something to do with people's decisions. I would just plead for a little more time taken on such decisions.

Comment: I voted to close this question because I thought it was about soundproofing. Is it about soundproofing?

Comment: @innisfree: Yes, it is about soundproofing a particular specialized type of equipment used only by experimental physicists. Suppose I were to ask about how to stabilize a laser; would that be accepted here? Given the links provided above by dmckee, I think closing this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, on the one hand, this isn't a question about physics, but, on the other, you want a practical piece of information that only a physicist might have. I can see cases for and against closing.

Comment: @innisfree: I tried an Area 51 proposal for a dedicated low temperature physics site, but several folks are complaining that the types of questions proposed for it really should be asked here. I think a lot of people agree with this as evidenced by the existence of the experimental-technology tag! "Physics" does not mean "parts of physics which don't actually involve building things." The implied definition of "physics" expressed by voting to close this and similarly oriented questions is a constant source of displeasure for experimentalists. That should be enough of a reason to not close it.

Comment: @innisfree: Also, if there's doubt about whether or not to close, which there clearly is given your previous comment, shouldn't the benefit of the doubt should be given to the question?

Comment: I think this should _not_ be closed, since it is pretty clearly about experimental physics - but I don't feel it would be appropriate for me to _unilaterally_ reopen it. If a few other people did so first, I would definitely vote to reopen. In the meantime I wonder if another meta post would help matters...

Comment: I think this question was overly hastily closed. It's 100% on-topic as far as I'm concerned

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/experimental-physics-engineering

Comment: We are now somewhat convinced the sound actually travels through the helium lines. This isn't that surprising I suppose, given how the remote head works. We're going to try wrapping the lines in plastic tube. Will report back if/when it does/doesn't work.

Comment: Wrapping the He lines made a really big difference. Anyone reading this: go around your system and at each point, the system with the metal end of a screwdriver while touching the handle of the screwdriver to your skull. This will help you hear vibrations. You will find the noisiest points. Wrap these points in plastic tubing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid we've found no real solution to this problem. I think the noise propagates through the support frame, and sound proofing doesn't help very much. I think your best bet is either noise cancelling headphones or remote desktop as much as possible. But neither solution will help other people who may be in the same lab.

Comment: Did you guys try anything to isolate compressor hardware from the fridge itself?

Comment: The compressor can be a long way from the fridge (up to 100 ft on a BlueFors fridge, I believe) and the still pump can likewise be fairly distant. They can be electrically and mechanically isolated in the same way you would isolate any pump. But I remember asking OI about the pulse tubes and they gave the impression there was nothing to be done.

Comment: What I meant was that you can mount the remote head so that it's not mechanically connected to the stand holding up the cryostat. We did that by attaching it to the ceiling near the fridge.

Comment: I just had a look at our fridge and I see what you mean. We haven't tried that, but we have no more room above the frame to do so. Interesting suggestion though.